# How do I get a class from an external .jar from a different computer?

Tags: java

I'm building a video game and I've built a launcher for my video game as well. The launcher downloads .jar files and stores them in the %appdata% folder for each person who buys the game and downloads the launcher and then runs it.

I need to be able to write a few lines of code to tell the launcher to get the .jar file from the user's computer and run a file from there. The .jar is already compiled and everything is okay and whatnot, but I'm not quite sure how to get the .class file to work with.

Something like this might help:

```
import System.getPropery("user.home") + "/AppData/Roaming/GameNameHere/bin/game.jar" + ".runGame.class"
```

And then I could possible do something like this:

```
if (credentials == true) {
     runGame game = new runGame();
     game.start();
}
```

How would I do something like this? Thanks in advance.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

So, I looked the ClassLoader.java class and messed around with it for a bit, but nothing really worked well. What am I doing wrong?

```
private String location = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\myJar.jar";
URL url = new URL(location);

public Load() throws Exception {
    ClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{url}, getClass().getClassLoader());
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("gumptastic.MyClass", true, loader);
    Method method = clazz.getMethod("output");
    method.invoke(this);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new Load();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're familiar with this but 
I think you should look at class loaders.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html

I guess you would need to write a simple one for your particular needs.

Alternatively, it would be even easier if you just use URLClassLoader.
Below is a simple example. This program has no idea of the Gson class
at compile time. But it can successfully load it, create an instance of it,
and use it at runtime. It was tested on Windows 7.

You can download Google Gson from here.
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list

Then place the gson-2.2.4.jar file anywhere you like 
on your computer, then point this program to it by
setting arr[0] in the proper way.

Then observe the magic that is taking place :)

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;


public class Test007 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL[] arr = new URL[1];
        arr[0] = new URL("file:///dir1/dir2/dir3/gson-2.2.4.jar");
        URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(arr);
        Class cls = loader.loadClass("com.google.gson.Gson");
        System.out.println(cls);
        Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor(new Class[0]);
        Object obj = constructor.newInstance(new Object[0]);
        System.out.println(obj);
        if (obj!=null){
            System.out.println("OK, so now we have an instance of:");
            System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually, I thought it worked, but it didn't. Could you give me a basic example? I don't actually understand those Oracle tutorials. Still a bit of a noob. :/